# What is the best structure to save incremental subfolders?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ext3

I have 3 different folders containing particular information about sales orders. Everything was working fine but a few days ago I started having an issue about the amount of subdirectories in each of those main folders (orders above 32K).

My temporary solution was to move the oldest data to a backup and remove it from the production environment but I would really like to have it there, so my question is:

What options do you recommend to store a structure where I can save incremental subfolders without hitting the maximum? I am on a Ubuntu server box with ext3

It looks something like

-tmp/
 --order_1/
 --order_2/
...
--order_32000/
...
-imgs/
--order_1/
--order_2/
...
--order_32000/
...
-hd_imgs/
--order_1/
--order_2/
...
--order_32000/

inside each order_xx folder live around 1 to 30 files.

Comment: How large are these files, and what is the meaning of the top level directories ( tmp, imgs, hd_imgs )?

Comment: @psusi no real way to say the file size it varies a lot but some files can be up to 200M. tmp - every file that the user uploads before he is logged in which then gets moved to imgs with the propper order number which then gets moved to hd_imgs after we have worked on the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a (real) database (as opposed to the filesystem), and some development time to make a front end for it.  Investigate [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org).

---

If you need a faster solution, try breaking up your orders by time: Store them in a hierarchy like `[year]/[month]/order_######` (you can keep using serial order numbers if you want, or compose the order number as `YYYYMM#####` so it's easier to find in the system later without having to do searches within the directory hierarchy).

This will work as long as the number of orders in a month is less than about 30,000 or so.  The next limit you will hit is the `filesystem inode limit` though, and the only solution there is a new filesystem (or splitting your data across several filesystems). Take a look at `df -i` on your system today, and remember that every file and directory will chew up one more inode.  Eventually you'll run out.

Comment: just checked my inodes, have just 1% used so I'm thinking that shouldn't be a problem. Also the year/month/order solution seems very good for me since we don't have that many sales per month. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you only have 32K*3(tmp,imgs,hd_imgs) directories and there aren't that many files under them you're not really in danger of hitting the inode limit (it's usually into the hundreds of millions of files) -- More something to be aware of as you scale up (say around the time you may be hitting 32K orders in a month), by which time hopefully you'll have a better database in place :)

Comment: thanks for the illustration @voretaq7 ... and agreed, that'd be a good problem to have ^__^

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade to ext4 to get around the 32k limit.